# Multiple radio buttons in Kendo UI grid with inline and batch editing

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, radio-button, kendo-grid

I thought I would be doing something simple as Kendo UI already can do so much, alas it is not as simple as I thought. Radio buttons make it hard.

I'm trying to create a permission mask just as you can see here:

[image]

And the corresponding, almost working JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/oz0b7xcu/

Currently I have `View`, `Edit` and `None` as separate columns - I can imagine them being an `enum`.

I figured out how to use a `template` & `editor` per `field` as to display the `boolean` with radio buttons instead of *"true"/"false"*.

My problems:

- Currently the inline editor only reacts when I click **next** to the radio button. Only after activating it I can select it. After "leaving" the field, the value is not persisted. (Try it out in the JSFiddle)
- How do I create the "Save changed permissions" button? I would need one event per changed permission and add it to some array
- How would I make it work over several pages, persisting the current permission "change set"
- How do I set the edited row as "dirty"/"changed"?

I think what I am trying to do is pretty clear:

- I have a list of users with permissions
- I want to be able to quickly edit all users (batch) and just select view/edit/none (exclusive)
- Maybe have a visualization for changed rows (dirty)
- When I'm done, I want to get a list of all changed permissions

PS: Maybe all of this would be easier with "virtual columns"? Have only one `PermissionMask` field and depending on its value virtual columns are filled. Possible? Maybe a better solution? I don't depend on any data source so I could define something different here...

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have any other editable fields except radio buttons, I feel you don't need to make the grid editable and you can still make it work. I made some changes to the code in your fiddle. here is the code. (only code that is changed)

```
columns: [
            { field: "Name" }, {
                field: "View",
                width: "80px",
                template: "<input type='radio' name='#: uid #' onclick='markDirty(this);' />"
            }, {
                field: "Edit",
                width: "80px",
                template: "<input type='radio' name='#: uid #' onclick='markDirty(this);' />"
        }, {
            field: "None",
            width: "80px",
            template: "<input type='radio' name='#: uid #' onclick='markDirty(this);'/>"
```

We can manually mark a record as dirty when selection is changed.

```
function markDirty(ctrl) {
        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.getByUid(ctrl.name).dirty = true;
    }
```

Finally you can get the data source from the grid on button click and perform any action required.

```
//this will have the data in an array
var data = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
```

Hope this helps.